# Is it common to say "the doctor gave my leg a check-up"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

According to my research, it seems "**a check-up**" is often refereed to a complete **whole-body **check-up (ears, eyes, lungs, blood test etc).

I am not sure if "**a check-up**" can be used for some part of our body (like legs, ear, eyes etc) separately.

I googled "**gave my leg a check-up**" but I don't see many results or too few results.

So I think native people don't often say that way. They probably say something else.

Can "**a check-up**" be used for some part of our body (like legs, ear, eyes etc) separately?

Comment: It most certainly cannot be used like that except informally in chats.

Answer (score 6):

A check-up most commonly refers to a routine general examination that isn't particularly focused in one area. That said, some sensitive/delicate parts of the body are routinely checked, so it would be possible to have a dental check-up, or an eye or ear check-up. It would be odd to have a check-up on a part of the body that does not usually see routine evaluation by a doctor, like the leg or elbow - if the doctor is examining your leg, it's usually because you're complaining about a specific problem, which does not fit well with the connotation that a check-up is usually a routine and exploratory procedure that's not intended to address a specific issue. A check-up implies that nothing specific is wrong, but checking one specific part of the body implies a specific issue.

If you hurt your leg and are seen by a doctor, it would be more common to say "the doctor **examined** my leg" than to say "the doctor gave my leg a check-up".

Comment: Yes, "examined" is the word

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use *checkup*, in the sense that people would probably understand what you meant, but you're correct that it's not common.

As you've found, *checkup* is more often used for a general examination:

> 2. *medicine*
>    a medical examination, esp one taken at regular intervals to verify a normal state of health or discover a disease in its early stages

[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/checkup)

The correct phrase would depend on the level of formality of the conversation and the intensity of the examination.  For example, if I wanted to de-emphasize the seriousness, I could say:

> I asked the doctor to *check out* my leg

A similar tone, though somewhat more serious:

> I asked the doctor to *look at* my leg

If you wanted to be formal, or stress the seriousness:

> I asked the doctor to *examine* my leg